# Find the probability that at least one card is a diamond when two cards are drawn

Tags: probability

the question is 
**"Find the probability that at least one card is a diamond when two cards are drawn" (without replacement)**

I was a little confused on how to approach this question but I tried anyways and this is my attempt:

---

$P(\text{atleast 1D}) = P(1D) + P(2D)$

 $= \frac{13}{52} + (\frac{13}{52})(\frac{12}{51})$

 $= \frac{21}{68}$

---

**Can you let me know if this approach is correct.** Also is there a generic way to approach this type of problem? I meen I just made this up in my head but is there a generic formula?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For at least statements there are two general approaches - break it down into the individual pieces and add them all up (like you did) or find the complement and subtract that from $1$.

$P(\geq 1D) = P(1D) + P(2D) = \left(\dfrac{13}{52}\dfrac{39}{51} + \dfrac{39}{52}\dfrac{13}{51}\right) + \dfrac{13}{52}\dfrac{12}{51} = \dfrac{15}{34}$, where the piece in parentheses is the correct probability for drawing exactly one diamond.

Alternatively, the complement of at least one diamond is less than one diamond. $P(<1D) = P(0D) = \dfrac{39}{52}\dfrac{38}{51} = \dfrac{19}{34}$. Then $P(\geq 1D) = 1 - P(<1D) = 1-\dfrac{19}{34} = \dfrac{15}{34}$.

Answer (score 1):

It's the right idea, obtaining exactly one diamond and obtaining exactly two diamonds are exclusive events, so we sum their probabilities.  However, the calculation of $P(1D)$ is buggy (the formula you use is the probability of picking a diamond with one card, rather than exactly one diamond with two cards).

We should have
\begin{align*}
P(1D) &= P(\text{D first, then non-D})+P(\text{non-D first, then D}) \\
 &= \frac{13}{52}\frac{39}{51}+\frac{39}{52}\frac{13}{51} \\
 &= \frac{13}{34}.
\end{align*}
or equivalently
\begin{align*}
P(1D) &= P(\text{exactly one D}) \\
 &= \frac{\binom{13}{1}\binom{39}{1}}{\binom{52}{2}} \\
 &= \frac{13}{34}.
\end{align*}